# Rudimentary Text Editor: passing a 1d string back to a 2d string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

For an assignment I am tasked with creating a very simple text editor. I have a 2d string with 5 rows of pre-set text.
The editor must(in order):

1. Ask the user to select a row of text while also showing the rows to choose from with each lines text.
2. Ask the user which operation to be performed(entire line or substring).
3. Display results and ask to edit again.

My problem is once I ask the user to edit again, the row of text I edited is not updated thus not displayed in the recently printed 2d string array. I think its a problem with passing a 1d array back into a 2d array?

The functions in my code are required and the parameters in them cannot be changed in any way. With the exception of function 'editAgain', that function is free to be changed in anyway, new functions are also allowed.

Im aware this compiles with an error or two but its related with my problem of passing back the 1d string 'original' to the 2d string 'buffer'.

Thanks in advance!

## define ROWS 5

## define COLS 81

int replaceEntireString(char original[], char substring[], char replace[]);

int editAgain(char buffer[][COLS], char substring[], char replace[]);

int main(void) {

```
char editDecision = '?';
int editOperation = 0;
char buffer[ROWS][COLS];
char substring[] = "?";
char replace[] = "?";
int editedLine = 0;

strcpy(buffer[0],"university of guelph");
strcpy(buffer[1],"university of guelph");
strcpy(buffer[2],"university of guelph");
strcpy(buffer[3],"university of guelph");
strcpy(buffer[4],"university of guelph");

printf("\nWelcome to this very rudimentary text editor!\n");


while(editDecision != 'Y' && editDecision != 'y' && editDecision != 'N' && editDecision != 'n'){

    printf("\nWould you like to edit text? If not you will be exited: Y/N\n");
    scanf("%c", &editDecision);
    getchar();

    switch(editDecision){

        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            
            while(editedLine >= 0){
                
                printf("Choose a line to edit: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\n");
                printf("0: %s\n", buffer[0]);
                printf("1: %s\n", buffer[1]);
                printf("2: %s\n", buffer[2]);
                printf("3: %s\n", buffer[3]);
                printf("4: %s\n", buffer[4]);
                scanf("%d", &editedLine);
                getchar();
                
                if(editedLine > 4){
                    
                    printf("Invalid Entry!\n");
                }
                
                if(editedLine <= 4){
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            while(editOperation != 1 && editOperation != 2){
                
                printf("Choose an operation: 1. Replace entire line. 2. Replace a substring.\n");
                scanf("%d", &editOperation);
                getchar();
                
                switch(editOperation){
                        
                    case 1:
                        
                        replaceEntireString(buffer[editedLine], substring, replace);
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 2:
                        
                        replaceInString(buffer[editedLine], substring, replace);
                        
                        break;
                        
                    default:
                        
                        printf("Invalid Entry!\n");
                        
                        break;
                        
                }
                
            }

            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':

            printf("Unedited text:\n");
            printf("0: %s\n", buffer[0]);
            printf("1: %s\n", buffer[1]);
            printf("2: %s\n", buffer[2]);
            printf("3: %s\n", buffer[3]);
            printf("4: %s\n", buffer[4]);
            printf("Goodbye for now!\n");

            break;

        default:

            printf("Invalid Entry!\n");

            break;

    }
}

return 0;
```

}

int editAgain(char buffer[][COLS], char substring[], char replace[]){

```
char editDecision = '?';
int editOperation = 0;
int editedLine = 0;

while(editDecision != 'Y' && editDecision != 'y' && editDecision != 'N' && editDecision != 'n'){
    
    printf("\nWould you like to edit text? If not you will be exited: Y/N\n");
    scanf("%c", &editDecision);
    getchar();
    
    switch(editDecision){
            
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            
            while(editedLine >= 0){
                
                printf("Choose a line to edit: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\n");
                printf("0: %s\n", buffer[0]);
                printf("1: %s\n", buffer[1]);
                printf("2: %s\n", buffer[2]);
                printf("3: %s\n", buffer[3]);
                printf("4: %s\n", buffer[4]);
                scanf("%d", &editedLine);
                getchar();
                
                if(editedLine > 4){
                    
                    printf("Invalid Entry!\n");
                }
                
                if(editedLine <= 4){
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            while(editOperation != 1 && editOperation != 2){
                
                printf("Choose an operation: 1. Replace entire line. 2. Replace a substring.\n");
                scanf("%d", &editOperation);
                getchar();
                
                switch(editOperation){
                        
                    case 1:
                        
                        replaceEntireString(buffer[editedLine], substring, replace);
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 2:
                        
                        replaceInString(buffer[editedLine], substring, replace);
                        
                        break;
                        
                    default:
                        
                        printf("Invalid Entry!\n");
                        
                        break;
                        
                }
                
            }
            
            break;
            
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            
            printf("Unedited text:\n");
            printf("0: %s\n", buffer[0]);
            printf("1: %s\n", buffer[1]);
            printf("2: %s\n", buffer[2]);
            printf("3: %s\n", buffer[3]);
            printf("4: %s\n", buffer[4]);
            printf("Goodbye for now!\n");
            
            break;
            
        default:
            
            printf("Invalid Entry!\n");
            
            break;
            
    }
}

return 0;
```

}
int replaceEntireString(char original[], char substring[], char replace[]){

```
printf("Enter the new string text: \n");
fgets(original, COLS, stdin);

if(original[strlen(original)-1] == '\n'){
    
    original[strlen(original)-1] = '\0';
    
}

printf("\nThe edited line text is now: %s\n", original);

editAgain(original, substring, replace);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you recurse into `main`? Your function does never return. Is that supposed some overclever something or some missconception how functions work? Either way, you should retink what you are doing and maybe consulting your course material (or a good C book) would also be a good idea. Then see [ask] and provide a [mcve] with a **clear and specific** problem description and details about what you get from debugging the code.

Comment: sorry first time doing this

Comment: Ignorantia legis non excusat. And quantity is not the same as quality. Did  you even have a look at the text after the edit?

Comment: cool thanks for helping guys...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the line:

```
main();
```

in `replaceEntireString`.

You are adding another call to `main` in the call stack and creating the strings all over again. The variables in the newly entered `main` have no relationship to the variables in the previous `main`.

Remove that line.

Comment: sorry that wasn't suppose to be in there, I added the correct function.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `replaceEntireString` functon you *call* `main` instead of just returning to the point where `replaceEntireString` was called. Then a new stack frame is created with a **new** set of variables. Those new variables — the new `buffer` among them — are initialized, so you start again and againd the same work, never completeing those previously started.

The cure: remove the

```
    main();
```

line from your `replaceEntireString` function.

Comment: sorry that wasn't suppose to be in there, I added the correct function.